# Linkedin integration in android error: not showing authorization screen in linkedin app

Tags: android, authentication, linkedin-api

I am trying to build an android app with linkedin integration while login,  but I am getting an error after pressing the button. It is redirecting to linkedin app but not showing any authorization screen and redirecting to my app.

```
Code:
     LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).init(this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {
            // Authentication was successful.  You can now do
            // other calls with the SDK.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Authrization Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fetchDetailsLinkedin();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
            Log.e("Auth Error",error.toString());
            // Handle authentication errors
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Authrization Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, true);
```

while it is showing authorization failure.
The error massage it is showing.

> com.example.loginintegration E/Auth Error: {
>         "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
>         "errorMessage": "The passed in mobile identifier is invalid \"com.example.loginintegration\""
>       }

Here `com.example.loginintegration` is my package name.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Install and signin with linkedIn app on your device

Comment: I have installed and tried but its not working

Comment: you should use oauth 2.0 for login

Comment: Did you got the solution? i am also facing same issue

Comment: you found any solution for this? @Raghavendra

Comment: @RickyPatel Did you got the solution?'

Answer (score -3):

Your hash key on linkedIn developer console is incorrect. Use the below function to generate the hash key and paste on the developer console. It will works like a charm. cheers!!!

```
fun generateHashKey() {
        try {
            val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                    application.packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
            for (signature in info.signatures) {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                md.update(signature.toByteArray())
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT))
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {

        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where i need to pass key hash? Because i did not found on developer console

Comment: have you found where to enter hase key? @KrutikaChotara

Comment: have you found yet??

Comment: @KrutikaChotara have you found where to enter hash key?